# Как добавить ключ - значение в словарь Python при этом в значении должно быть первое слово существующего значения

Tags: python

Задачка такая, есть список со словарями например:

```
users = [{"last_name": "Holy", "full_name": "Jack Holy",},{"last_name": "Adams","full_name": "Mike Adams",}]
```

Нужно создать в словаре новый ключ `first_name` со значением имени (то есть взять первое значение `Mike` или `Jack` из ключа full_name и добавить к новому ключу `first_name`). Не могу понять как брать именно первое значение из ключа `full_name` и добавить в новый ключ `first_name`?
Попытка решения:

```
def restore_names(users: list) -> None:
    for new_dict in users:
        if 'first_name' not in new_dict:
            new_dict['first_name'] = new_dict.get('full_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Докину вариант

```py
from pprint import pp
import re

users = [
    {"last_name": "Holy", "full_name": "Jack Holy"},
    {"last_name": "Adams", "full_name": "Mike Adams"}
]

for user in users:
    user.update(
        re.search(r'^(?P<first_name>\w+)?', user.get('full_name', '')).groupdict()
    )

pp(users)
```

---

```
[{'last_name': 'Holy', 'full_name': 'Jack Holy', 'first_name': 'Jack'},
 {'last_name': 'Adams', 'full_name': 'Mike Adams', 'first_name': 'Mike'}]
```

---

##### Если немного развить тему, то может получиться следующее:

```py
from pprint import pp
import re

users = [{"full_name": "Jack Holy"}, {"full_name": "Mike"}]

for user in users:
    user.update(
        re.search(
            r'^(?P<first_name>\w+)?\s*(?P<last_name>\w+)?$',
            user.get('full_name', '')
        ).groupdict()
    )

pp(
    users
)
```

---

```
[{'full_name': 'Jack Holy', 'first_name': 'Jack', 'last_name': 'Holy'},
 {'full_name': 'Mike', 'first_name': 'Mike', 'last_name': None}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно изменить данный список словарей:

```
def f(users):
    for user in users:
        full_name = user['full_name']
        first_name = full_name.split()[0]
        user['first_name'] = first_name

f(users)
print(users)
```

Если вам нужно не менять, а создать новый:

```
def f(users):
    new_users = []
    for user in users:
        full_name = user['full_name']
        first_name = full_name.split()[0]
        last_name = user['last_name']
        new_user = {
            'first_name': first_name,
            'last_name': last_name,
            'full_name': full_name,
        }
        new_users.append(new_user)
    return new_users

new_users = f(users)
print(new_users)
```

---

Сокращенная версия первого кода:

```
def f(users):
    for user in users:
        user['first_name'] = user['full_name'].split()[0]
```

Второго кода:

```
def f(users):
    return [{'first_name': user['full_name'].split()[0],
            'last_name': user['last_name'],
            'full_name': user['full_name']} for user in users]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое